# Node - How to pack several files form different paths into one zip file and how to unpack them?

Tags: node.js, zip, gzip, archive, tar

Currently I'm using [node-archive](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver) to pack (because of the nice bulk API). I'm setting gzip to true. However, the [node-tar](https://github.com/npm/node-tar) I'm using can't extract it. it says

```
An error occurred: { [Error: invalid tar file]
```

Thanks!